# phpdoc @return with lazy loading

Tags: return, phpdoc

I don't know how to documents my methods for autocompletion.

My model Training has a getAnimators() method who returns a Db_MysqlResult which implements SeekableIterator and Countable. This Db_MysqlResult will create my Animator objects when I iterates on it, for example :

```
<?php
foreach ($training->getAnimators() as $animator) {
    // Autocompletion shows me next, seek, etc. not getName
    echo $animator->getName(); 
}
?>
```

I can write @return Animators[] in my getAnimators() even if it is not true because it returns a Db_MysqlResult?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for your $animator variable to autocomplete its methods, your best bet may be to add an @var line hint in there:

```
/** @var Animator $animator */
echo $animator->
```

Some IDEs have the ability to recognize that @var line as a type hint and use it to give you autocompletion.

However, I'm not aware of any IDE that will recognize your return value of $training->getAnimators() and automatically know the type for $animator just from them being tied together in that foreach().

Comment: That is what I am doing but I would have liked to avoid it. My problem is not how to get the autocompletion for my var $animator but how to write my phpdoc in accordance with the way my objects are load.

Comment: Ok, I was thrown off by your first statement then, "how to documents my methods for autocompletion".

Based on your description that getAnimators() does actually pre-generate the Animator objects and returns the SeekableIterator collection (like an array, but not exactly an array), then it seems to me that "@return Animator[]" to indicate that collection of Animator objects is the "right" way to document it.  It should show "Animator[]" rather than "Animators[]" though, since each member of the "array" is a single Animator instance.

Comment: The class is instantiate when I am in the "current" method of SeekableIterator so at first my collection does not contains my Animator objects, that is the problem.

But as you say it is fine to write @return Animator[] so I will write it.